# Python read columns until end of line

Tags: python, csv

I have to read from an csv all columns starting from the forth column. For example from row[4] until the end of line. Any ideas how I achieve that?

```
for col in range(4,row):
            covid.addCell(row[col])
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? where is your code/attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns rows as lists, so you can [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) each row to get a list made of the columns from the fourth to the final column

```
import csv

with open('mycsv.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        chunk = row[3:]
        # do something with chunk (which is a list)
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Where is your code/attempt?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("XXX.csv")
df_selected = df.iloc[ :, 3: ] # from 4th column, reminder: in python we count from 0
```

Comment: I'm not using pandas, but csv module. I haven't attempted anything yet, I'm kinda stuck. I know how to do it statically (row[0], row[1]...) but not dynamically because csv columns update everyday

Comment: post your code and the data to be able to help more

Comment: I updated with an initial attempt but I have no idea if that's correct